# DirectAdmin Blocks after 100 non-existing emails

Tags: email, directadmin

I have installed phplist on the server for E-mail marketing but when it has send 100 E-mails to non-existing adresses DirectAdmin blocks the email account.

[image]

When this happends I must change the password but I have a list of 30.000 E-mails which needs to bounce first so I know which E-mails to delete from the database.

Is there a way to avoid the blocking and keep on sending E-mails to non-existing adresses?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have setup mail limit on your server and due to that you are facing this issues, Please check following direct-admin help docs and try to update your mail limit.

https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=81